# IE 6 strange problem background bullet only shown on mouse while hover is not applied?

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

in IE6 background image only shows if we mouse over on the link otherwise not

```
#tbaContentContainer P A:link { font-size:1em; background: url(~/media/images/e/experian/images/content/arrow.ashx) no-repeat -2px 5px ; color: red; text-indent: 15px;position:relative}
```

Attached here is a screenshot for more information.

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/428/9459264109.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/428/9459264109.jpg)

Can someone please look into this and advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often a hasLayout problem.  See if adding "zoom:1" to the link fixes it.  If you want valid CSS, add "height: 1%;" to an IE6-targeted stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

IE6 has some minor quirks when it comes to `a` tags.  Have you tried explicitly adding the background to `a:link` as well as just `a`?  Something like:

```
#tba-contentContainer p a, #tba-contentContainer p a:link, #tba-contentContainer p a:visited, #tba-contentContainer p a:hover {
    background: transparent url(~/media/Images/E/Experian/Images/content/arrow.ashx) no-repeat scroll -2px 5px
```